# [C#]Printing many DataGrids in one page

Tags: c#, printing, datagrid, code-behind

Is there a way in C# to print e.g. 2 DataGrids and one Listbox in one page?
My customer asks me for such a printout, but I can't cope with it.

[My 2-datagrids and 1-listbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9f6XH.png)

Comment: what will happen if grid has more data and going out of page? Is it windows application or web application ?

Comment: @AmitVerma Windows application (C# WinForms)